# How to make an update query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table with five fields,

| Zip code | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Code |

my table and its data below i have tones of records like this so there are many duplicate data for fields [data 1], [data2] and [data 3]

```
 Zip | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Code |
 123 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |_____ |
 234 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |_____ |
 456 | __A__ |__ B__ |______ |_____ |
 678 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |_____ |
 981 | __A__ |__ B__ |______ |_____ |
```

my goal is to find the matching row values so i have a set of unique row from them (which i created by a query this gave me )

```
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Code |
| __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |_____ |
| __A__ |__ B__ |______ |_____ |
```

What i wanted to do with this was just enter a code value in that query so it reflects on the existing table and displays the code in all duplicate values ,

so say i enter this data in the query,( which i cannot enter for some reason )

```
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Code |
| __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |__C1__ |
| __A__ |__ B__ |______ |__C2__ |
```

i want the following output in the table

```
Zip | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Code |
123 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |__C1__ |
234 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |__C1__ |
456 | __A__ |__ B__ |______ |__C2__ |
678 | __A__ |__ B__ |__ C__ |__C1__ |
981 | __A__ |__ B__ |______ |__C2__ |
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select your distinct values and insert them into a temporary table or scratch table:

```
TempTable
Data1
Data2
Data3
Code null
```

Next, insert distinct rows into your table

```
insert into TempTable (Data1, Data2, Data3)
select distinct data1, data2, data3 from myTable
```

Next, update your temp table with whatever code you want for each record. Still not sure if you have a specific value in mind or if you want it to be just a "unique" value. If a unique value, you could set code to be an identity and skip this step

```
update temptable set Code = '' where Data1 = x and Data2 = y and Data3 = z
```

Lastly, update your original table with the values

```
update myTable
inner join tempTable 
   on [myTable].data1 = [tempTable].data1 
      and [myTable].data2 = [tempTable].data2 
      and [myTable].data3 = [tempTable].data3
  set [myTable].Code = [tempTable].Code;
```

Comment: how can i do that distinct and update part you just mentioned within access 2007 ? and this is exactly what i  need!

Comment: Exactly as it is written. Both should be valid or close to valid sql. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HA001231351.aspx

Comment: I like the idea of a temp/scratch table. However, if the 'blanks' in the OP's data are nulls then your SQL will not work. Hint: `myTable.data3 = tempTable.data3` should be more like `((myTable.data3 = tempTable.data3) OR (myTable.data3 IS NULL AND tempTable.data3 IS NULL))`